# Using chmod command in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to execute a chmod command in my shell script but I get the following error:

```
 chmod: missing operand after "777"
Try "chmod --help" for more informations.
```

This is an important piece of my code:

```
caminhoPadrao="/usr/local/lib/"
...
chmod -R 777 $caminhoPadrao
```

Bellow is my FULL SCRIPT.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

##Definicao de Variaveis
echo "Digite a velocidade da sua ECF: "; read velocidade

caminhoCaixaProperties="`~/folds/myfile.dot`"
caminhoDados="`~/folds/DarumaFramework/`"
caminhoPadrao="/usr/local/lib/"
caminhoAuxiliarConf="/usr/local/share/DarumaFramework"
libDarumaFramework="libDarumaFramework.so"
liblebin="liblebin.so"
libLeituraMFDBin="libLeituraMFDBin.so"

#Valores do MD5
md5libDarumaFramework="908bd049bb5a3c28f58f3a1c907b5f50"
md5liblebin="328378ef909491e62274c42000b50d31"
md5libLeituraMFDBin="c5f0882b5c242231225ad41dd9a1737c"

#Tempo de espera entre processos
timer=1

#Mensagens
sucesso="--->OK"

clear
echo "Checando configurações para funcionamento da coleta MFD..."
echo ""

echo "Procurando $libDarumaFramework em $caminhoPadrao"
sleep $timer
if [ -e $caminhoPadrao$libDarumaFramework ];
then 
 echo $sucesso
else 
 echo "A biblioteca $libDarumaFramework nao foi encontrada em $caminhoPadrao"
 exit
fi

echo ""
echo "Procurando $liblebin em $caminhoPadrao"
sleep $timer
if [ -e $caminhoPadrao$liblebin ];
then 
 echo $sucesso
else 
 echo "A biblioteca $liblebin nao foi encontrada em $caminhoPadrao"
  exit
fi

echo ""
echo "Procurando $libLeituraMFDBin em $caminhoPadrao"
sleep $timer
if [ -e $caminhoPadrao$libLeituraMFDBin ];
then 
 echo $sucesso
else 
 echo "A biblioteca $libLeituraMFDBin nao foi encontrada em $caminhoPadrao"
  exit
fi

clear
echo "Checando versao das bibliotecas..."

sleep $timer
chk=`md5sum $caminhoPadrao$libDarumaFramework`
md5Atual=`echo $chk | cut -f1 -d " "`
if [ "$md5libDarumaFramework" != "$md5Atual" ];
then 
 echo "A versão da biblioteca $libDarumaFramework nao esta correta"
  exit
fi


sleep $timer
chk=`md5sum $caminhoPadrao$liblebin`
md5Atual=`echo $chk | cut -f1 -d " "`
if [ "$md5liblebin" != "$md5Atual" ];
then 
 echo "A versão da biblioteca $liblebin nao esta correta"
  exit
fi

sleep $timer
chk=`md5sum $caminhoPadrao$libLeituraMFDBin`
md5Atual=`echo $chk | cut -f1 -d " "`
if [ "$md5libLeituraMFDBin" != "$md5Atual" ];
then 
 echo "A versão da biblioteca $libLeituraMFDBin nao esta correta"
  exit
fi

 echo $sucesso
 sleep $timer

 clear
 echo "Alterando permissao dos diretorios e arquivos para 777..."

 chmod -R 777 $caminhoPadrao
 sleep $timer

 chmod -R 777 $caminhoDados
 sleep $timer 

 chmod 777 $caminhoCaixaProperties
 sleep $timer

 chmod -R 777 $caminhoAuxiliarConf

 echo $sucesso
 sleep $timer

 clear
 echo "Checando consistencia do ld.so.conf..."
 echo $sucesso
 sleep $timer

 clear 
 echo "Configurando portas ECF..."

 for((x=0;x<=10;x++))
 do
 sleep $timer
 if [ -e "/dev/ttyS$x" ]
  then
  sudo chmod 777 "/dev/ttyS$x"
  stty -F "/dev/ttyS$x $velocidade"
 fi

  if [ -e "/dev/ttyUSB$x" ]
  then
  sudo chmod 777 "/dev/ttyUSB$x"
  stty -F "/dev/ttyUSB$x $velocidade"
 fi

 done

 sudo chmod 777 "/dev/ttyS*"
 sudo chmod 777 "/dev/ttyU*"

 clear
 echo "Iniciando testes na ECF ..."

 for((x=0;x<=10;x++))
 do
  sleep $timer

 if [ -e "/dev/ttyS$x" ]
  then 
  echo "teste" >> "/dev/ttyS$x"
  echo "teste" >> "/dev/ttyS$x"
  echo "teste" >> "/dev/ttyS$x"

  echo "A ECF 'cuspiu' papel ? [sim/nao]"; read portaEncontrada

  if [ $portaEncontrada=="sim" ] then
   portaDefinitiva="/dev/ttyS$x"
   echo "ECF conectada em $portaDefinitiva"
   break
  fi

 fi

  if [ -e "/dev/ttyUSB$x" ]
  then
  echo "teste" >> "/dev/ttyUSB$x"
  echo "teste" >> "/dev/ttyUSB$x"
  echo "teste" >> "/dev/ttyUSB$x"  

  echo "A ECF 'cuspiu' papel ? [sim/nao]"; read portaEncontrada

  if [ $portaEncontrada=="sim" ] then
   portaDefinitiva="/dev/ttyUSB$x"
   echo "ECF conectada em $portaDefinitiva"
   break
  fi
 fi

 done


 echo "Processo Finalizado com sucesso"
 exit
```

Comment: Maybe the error is not in these 2 lines of code. Make a complete example that shows the error.

Comment: Try echoing caminhoPadrao before that statement.

Comment: I already tried echo the $caminhoPadrao and the variable apper normal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
caminhoCaixaProperties="`~/folds/myfile.dot`"
caminhoDados="`~/folds/DarumaFramework/`"
```

You use '`' execution attribute, and I am pretty sure you see before your message lines like that:

```
bash: ~/folds/myfile.dot: command not found
```

and

```
bash: ~/folds/DarumaFramework/: is a directory
```

Because of these errors, both variables become "" and then you run command `chmod 777` which is missing file name argument.

Remove "`" from the file / directory names, and you will be good.

Comment: If i remove the "`" i got another error: 
chmod: impossible access "~/folds/DarumaFramework/": File or directory not found

Comment: @user2776409: Change ~ to $HOME

Comment: Can you help me with another problem ? I got the following error: 

"stty: /dev/ttyS0 123: File or directory not found".

when i try to execute the "stty -F ..."

Comment: Like in `stty -F "/dev/ttyS$x $velocidade"` ? You need to remove your quotes: `stty -F /dev/ttyS$x $velocidade`. With quotes, your `stty` command has two, not three arguments, and the second one is "/dev/ttyS0 123" instead of having two: /dev/ttys0, and 123.

Comment: thats works, but i got now the following error: 

./checaEcfParaMfd.sh: line 157: sintaxe error near to `token' don't  waiting for `fi'

Comment: You have at least two lines that will create this error. You need to use `then` in the next line - not the line where the `if` starts (like you did in other places.) As a matter of fact you can use `then` in the same line but you need to do this in this form: `if [ expression ]; then`

Answer (score 0):

see if this works

```
$(chmod -R 777 $caminhoPadrao )
```

Comment: the error continue, didn't work. I posted all my code in post